# iTunes Connect Create new app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to create a new app on iTunes Connect. I have filled in the form however it says "Your app information could not be saved. Information for atleast one field is invalid or is in the wrong format"

However it doesn't tell me what is wrong, so no clue about how I should go about this. (I also tried different browsers hoping one would work).

Here is a screenshot of the form:

[image: Screenshot of form]

Comment: I think version numbers can only have three parts (two periods), yours has four parts.

Comment: Just tried changing that, didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any restriction on version number, but have you tried changing your SKU ? I always keep my bundle ID and SKU same (as it's already unique).

I couldn't add comment hence writing it as an answer.

Comment: Tried that. No success